# HMAC, RS and Base64 in Rust

Tags: encryption, base64, rust, hmac

I have a project in which RS and HMAC 256...512 are involved and base64. Is there any way to do encoding and decoding in such the algorithms in Rust already? If so, is it safe to them now, at this point of Rust development stage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(By 'RS' I'm assuming you're speaking of RS256 and siblings, which are identifiers defined in [RFC7518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.1) for specific suites of asymmetric cryptography using RSA and SHA2 functions.)

These three algorithms are vastly different:

- HMAC is an authentication algorithm often used alongside symmetric crypto, and it is *digest agnostic*; so you also need a library of digest / hash functions. [ring](https://briansmith.org/rustdoc/ring) is a pure-Rust high-quality implementation of various *mainstream* cryptographic algorithms, such as AES, HMAC, SHA1/2/3, AEAD, etc.
- RSA is a cryptosystem for public key cryptography. Ring, mentioned above, supports modern configurations of the system. For other/older configurations, you may use the [rust-openssl](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl) bindings, or [native-tls](https://crates.io/crates/native-tls).
- Base64 is a binary-to-text encoding (not encryption). The [base64 crate](https://docs.rs/base64) is the recommended way to handle it.

The question of how *safe* these are to use is highly subjective and depends on your use-case, and as such StackOverflow is not a good venue for that discussion.

Comment: You can mention Base64 encoding is typically applied to result of RSA encryption/signing or HMAC computation to transfer them in text-based protocols. While for binary based protocols typically ASN.1 is used.